# Make the first N downvotes on a question only count as 1/N

Tags: feature-request, questions, downvotes, voting

The first downvote on a question is much easier to get than any subsequent downvotes.

Having a -1 score, though, can prevent the submitter from receiving an answer.

I propose to give that -1 score only after several downvotes: the first three or four should have to add up to produce one "normal" downvote. This is the same principle as for closing a question: several voters have to agree for it to take effect.

After those first N, downvotes would act normally.

Comment: Why? What's the benefit to the community?

Comment: I'm more concerned with the benefit for the question submitter.

Comment: @Alex Then your priorities are the wrong way around. Hence the downvotes on this question.

Comment: What would be the benefit for the question submitter then?

Comment: Supposedly many experts won't even look at a question with a downvote. So, if the 1st downvote has a bigger weight than the subsequent ones, it would help to attract attention to the question (which with only 1 downvote might well be a fine question)

Comment: Isn't that a bit unfair to the person who writes a question that doesn't attract any downvotes?

Comment: "I'm more concerned with the benefit for the question submitter" - yeah, those poor souls who are unable to program, google, spell, or formulate a decent question _really_ need our deepest sympathy. Oh, wait, they don't - they rather need more down- and closevotes. We're overrun with enough crap already, making it harder to get bad questions to disappear from the front page doesn't exactly help here.

Comment: @i4mpi If by the nature of the question it is evident that the submitter can't program etc such a question will easily gather > 1 downvotes. Otherwise anyone can give it -1 on arbitrary priniciples. I can not be sure of your skills by the downvotes you are giving but rather by the solutions you are giving

Comment: Well, a Q is either downvoted or not.  I'm not at all convinced that the downvote arrow should be replaced with a 'Downvote sometimes' arrow.  It extends the lifetime of a bad question and increases the chances of some repwhore answering it, so further cluttering up the site with Q/A that are of no benefit to anyone else other than the OP, who gets their rubbish question answered and a few extra assignment marks that they do not deserve.

Comment: Also, not indicating downvotes will not incentivise the OP to improve their post before it gets closed/ignored.

Comment: @Alex let's just replace "downvote" and "-1" with "upvote" and "+1" in your last comment and we've established the same holds true for upvotes. So should we just disable voting completely? That would surely put an end to the endless discussions...

Comment: @l4mpi I agree, disabling up- and downvotes completely would be good

Comment: @l4mpi I have just submitted the item with that proposition.
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285416/upvotes-and-downvotes-should-be-disabled-completely

Comment: @l4mpi: Even Yahoo! Answers has votes. I think OP is SOL here.

Comment: @l4mpi Surely, I was thinking you were serious. Not knowing you outside of our cooperative work on improving the SO I surely have no reasons to think you were not serious.

Comment: I think this is a _terrible_ idea, but it's not a duplicate. I've edited and voted to reopen.

Comment: @Josh Caswell Not less terrible is the fact that anyone can do -1 on absolutely arbitrary principles. The weight of N is just to smooth out the possible randomness of the reasons for the downvoting.

There is a significant semantic  gap  between [ 0 -1] and [-1 -2]  intervals not reflected anywhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70340/discussion-between-alex-and-josh-caswell).

Comment: @Alex Not anyone; anyone with 125 rep on the site.  And of course, anyone with 15 rep on the site can reverse that action with an upvote, or give additional attention to a question for equally arbitrary reasons.  Such is the nature of voting.  Anyone using the site needs to be aware of that.

Answer (score 6):

Going with an N of 5, this would mean that 5 people would have to agree that the question deserves *one* downvote. Most people who downvote a question agree that it was not useful or was poorly researched, and as a result will typically vote to close that question.

At this point the question is closed, with a -1. No more answers may be posted, so that it has -1 or -50 doesn't really matter anymore from that angle, because the system directly prevents anyone from posting an answer.

I know the angle for this was to improve the overall quality of the site, but I do not think that ratcheting downvotes on questions does that. Downvotes on questions are essential for both screening bad content and screening users who continuously post bad content.

It honestly pains me when I see someone like Jon Skeet (I have seen this) edit a mediocre question and move on not answering it because of other issues it contains. Avoiding wasting the time of people whose time goes out to helping many users should be, in my opinion, at the forefront of consideration for changes to the site.

Comment: You are describing a  case when downvoting correlates with close voting. However many downvoted questions do not have any close requests. In fact, you are presuming that downvoting and close voting are related which they are not meant to be. I'm sure Jon Skeet can tell you more on that.

Comment: @Alex - The correlation between down voting and closing is very strong. While some questions do not have associated close reasons for how terrible they were, there often is. Further, why do you think they are not related? It literally says in the downvote tip that the question is "unclear" which just happens to be one of the closure reasons.