# Upvotes and downvotes on questions should be disabled completely

Tags: discussion, status-declined

There are many discussions regarding the intricacies of the upvoting and downvoting process.

To put an end to such discussions and concentrate more on the actual questions I propose to disable up- and downvoting completely.

Edited: I mean downvoting/upvoting on questions only.

Comment: Rather than disable upvoting/downvoitng can't we just disable the discussions on the subject?

Comment: [l4mpi will be pleased to see this.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285399/1-downvote-shall-have-a-bigger-weight-than-any-subsequent-downvotes#comment151828_285399)

Comment: What's the ratio of (discussion about voting) / (actual voting)? Is the discussion really getting in the way a significant proportion of the time?

Comment: Alternatively, just shut down SO entirely.  Might as well, if this proposal was actually implemented, which it won't be.

Comment: Oh - questions only.  Well, I suppose it would make the 'downvote or closevote' decision much easier.

Comment: I second this proposal, so I can enjoy all the future discussions titled "there is no way to tell good from bad, how about we introduce a way to vote".

Comment: ["A Modest Proposal"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Modest_Proposal)?

Comment: @Martin James This is one of the reasons such up/down voting is not needed. You will always be able to easily skip stupid/uninteresting questions.

Comment: If you were psychic and knew in advance that they should be skipped, yes.

Comment: [Feel free to browse around.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A..-2+is%3Aquestion) I'm sure you will find plenty of great questions among the 200K SO posts voted -2 or lower, to which you can direct your time and attention.

Comment: Why stop there? Forums are so awesome, let's just dispense with the formalities altogether and be one of those things.  Hell, we won't even need moderators; people will be able to do anything they want and ask about anything they want, even astrology.   What was the question again?

Answer (score 23):

With voting you give signals as to what's good content and what's not.

If you didn't have voting, how would you (as someone coming to the site with a problem) be able to tell which were the good solutions and which were the bad ones? Therefore, you'd know which solutions to check out first and which ones to avoid.

A slightly different argument applies to question - as someone who supplies answers you want to be able to decide where to direct your efforts. If you have two questions, one with a score of +5 (say) and another with a score of -1 then you can decide to answer the +5 question as it's more likely to be well written, clear and concise etc.

Either way you need voting.

Comment: What you have said is true for the answers only. This is not applicable to the questions. I've edited my questions, sorry, I was not clear.

Comment: That's quite the oversight...

Comment: @Alex Right, it's not applicable for questions because questions can't be objectively be good or bad, and there's absolutely no use in ranking them according to quality and usefulness, because the people who answer them have infinite time and patience. Disclaimer before you ask another question how to achieve having infinite time: I'm being sarcastic, which you don't seem to pick up too well.

Comment: @Alex votes also feed automatic deletion scripts. Without those SO would be even more swamped in crap and useless for people to try to find answers to useful questions.

Comment: @MichaelT However, I see no reason in automatic deletion of a question (as opposed to an answer).

Comment: @Alex I have down voted over 6k posts. Of those, only 1.5k remain. You would be surprised at the crap I have seen, but you don't have to anymore. Deleting questions is critical to keeping the quality above yahoo answers. And question bans too.

Comment: @MichaelT It is not evident how I was supposed to see that "crap" in case it had remained undeleted. It can be noted that seeing irrelevant crap does not usually stand in the way of finding some concrete answer to a well-formulated question.

Comment: @Alex search sucks in part because of all the false positives. Related questions often are half filled with poor questions. Removing them makes both these features more useful for finding good questions.

Comment: @MichaelT Is there an easy way to see that statistic for other users (me)?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis you can see my vote totals. I can also see all the things I down voted (profile votes tab). However, that only shows live posts - and there are only about 1500 of those listed. So you can see it for yourself, but not others.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @ChrisF's answer, votings on questions are  like a *magnet* for users actually.  As we know a question with high votes are more interesting than lower ones. So that, especially high vote questions causing more and more detailed answers. Even a question asked 4-5 years ago, still getting answers today because of high votes. That's why we need votes at the first place.

Also disable the up-downvoting completely means removing some tabs like `vote` tab. Which is terrible, since questions in that tab shows amazing answers to users. Like this question and answer: [What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python)